# Can't get the test methods run in parallel with selenium grid

Tags: java, selenium, parallel-processing, grid, testng

So I have have a selenium grid hub, a node registered with 5 instances for each browser (Safari 12.1.2, Firefox 69.0, Chrome 76.0). Whenever I try to run tests with methods in parallel and thread-count=2 or more I keep on getting errors informing about session creation issues. Weird, but tests in Chrome go through (sometimes tests in Safari go through as well). I'm confident test scripts are good. I believe the issue is related to the fact methods are sharing same browser sessions, although I implemented thread safety approach, however, there's must be something I missed. I think the problem lays somewhere in TestBase.class, not sure though. Running out of ides. Please advise.

Selenium Grid 3
Selenium-java libs: v 3.141.59
java.version: '11.0.4'
Safari 12.1.2, Firefox 69.0, Chrome 76.0

Here's my node with configs:

```
browserTimeout: 0

debug: false

help: false

port: 4445

role: node

timeout: 1800

cleanUpCycle: 5000

host: 169.254.129.238

maxSession: 5

capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 69.0, maxInstances: 5, platform: MAC, platformName: mac, se:CONFIG_UUID: 42a26507-e6b8-4463-a6e3-fd7..., seleniumProtocol: WebDriver}

capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 76.0, maxInstances: 5, platform: MAC, platformName: mac, se:CONFIG_UUID: c6a7fd21-84cb-4295-be81-cd6..., seleniumProtocol: WebDriver}

capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: safari, browserVersion: 12.1.2, maxInstances: 5, platform: MAC, platformName: mac, se:CONFIG_UUID: 606e350d-f4b7-405a-a772-6c7..., seleniumProtocol: WebDriver}

downPollingLimit: 2

hub: http://localhost:4444

id: http://169.254.129.238:4445

nodePolling: 5000

nodeStatusCheckTimeout: 5000

proxy: org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy

register: true

registerCycle: 5000

remoteHost: http://169.254.129.238:4445

unregisterIfStillDownAfter: 60000
```

```
My testng.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="3" name="Suite" parallel="tests">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="Base.TestListener"/>
        <!--<listener class-name="Base.RetryListener"/>-->
    </listeners>

    <parameter name="appURL" value="https://www.google.com"/>

    <test name="Chrome_tests"  parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <parameter name="browser_version" value="76.0"/>
        <parameter name="platform" value="mac"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.FirstTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="GOOGLE1" />
                    <include name="GOOGLE2" />
                    <include name="GOOGLE3" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>


    <test name="Firefox_tests" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
        <parameter name="browser_version" value="69.0"/>
        <parameter name="platform" value="mac"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.FirstTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="GOOGLE1"/>
                    <include name="GOOGLE2"/>
                    <!--<include name="GOOGLE3" />-->
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Second Test -->

    <test name="Safari_tests" parallel="methods" thread-count="1">
        <parameter name="browser" value="safari"/>
        <parameter name="browser_version" value="12.1.2"/>
        <parameter name="platform" value="mac"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.FirstTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="GOOGLE1"/>
                    <include name="GOOGLE2"/>
                    <!--<include name="GOOGLE3" />-->
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Second Test -->
</suite>
```

My TestBase.class

```
    public class TestBase {
        //Declare ThreadLocal Driver (ThreadLocalMap) for ThreadSafe Tests
        public ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
        public CapabilityFactory capabilityFactory = new CapabilityFactory();

        @BeforeMethod
        @Parameters({"browser", "appURL", "browser_version", "platform"})
        public void setup (String browser, String appURL, String browser_version, String platform) throws MalformedURLException {
            //Set Browser to ThreadLocalMap
            driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilityFactory.getCapabilities(browser, browser_version, platform)));
            getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
            getDriver().navigate().to(appURL);
        }

        public WebDriver getDriver() {
            //Get driver from ThreadLocalMap
            return driver.get();
        }

        @AfterMethod
        public void tearDown() {
            getDriver().quit();
            driver.remove();
        }
    }
```

CapabilityFactory.class

```
    public class CapabilityFactory {
        public Capabilities capabilities;

        public Capabilities getCapabilities (String browser, String browser_version, String platform) {
            if (browser.equals("chrome"))
                capabilities = getChromeOptions(browser_version, platform, browser);
            if (browser.equals("firefox"))
                capabilities = getFirefoxOptions(browser_version, platform, browser);
            if (browser.equals("safari"))
                capabilities = getSafariOptions(browser_version, platform, browser);
            return capabilities;
        }

            //Get Chrome Options
            public ChromeOptions getChromeOptions(String browser_version, String platform, String browser) {
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            /*DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            cap.setCapability("browser_version", browser_version);
            cap.setCapability("os", platform);
            options.merge(cap);*/

                options.setCapability("browserVersion", browser_version);
                options.setCapability("platformName", platform);
                options.setCapability("browserName", browser);

            /*cap.setCapability("os_version", "10");
            cap.setCapability("resolution", "1024x768");
            cap.setCapability("name", "Bstack-[Java] Sample Test");*/
                /*options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
                options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");*/
                //options.addArguments("--incognito");
                return options;
            }

            //Get Firefox Options
            public FirefoxOptions getFirefoxOptions(String browser_version, String platform, String browser) {

                FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();


                /*System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/Sasha/Documents/Selenium_projects/testng_maven/SeleniumGrid/src/main/resources/geckodriver");*/
                options.setCapability("browserVersion", browser_version);
                options.setCapability("platformName", platform);
                options.setCapability("browserName", browser);
            /*DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            cap.setCapability("browser_version", browser_version);
            cap.setCapability("os", platform);
            options.merge(cap);*/
            /*FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            //Accept Untrusted Certificates
            profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
            profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
            //Use No Proxy Settings
            profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 0);
            //Set Firefox profile to capabilities
            options.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);*/
                return options;
            }

            public SafariOptions getSafariOptions(String browser_version, String platform, String browser) {
                SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
                options.setCapability("browserVersion", browser_version);
                options.setCapability("platformName", platform);
                options.setCapability("browserName", browser);
            /*FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            //Accept Untrusted Certificates
            profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
            profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
            //Use No Proxy Settings
            profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 0);
            //Set Firefox profile to capabilities
            options.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);*/
                return options;
            }
        }
```

FirstTest.class

```
    public class FirstTest extends TestBase {
        @Test
        public void GOOGLE1() {
            System.out.println("Google1 Test Started! " + "Thread Id: " +  Thread.currentThread().getId());
            getDriver().navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
            System.out.println("Google1 Test's Page title is: " + getDriver().getTitle() +" " + "Thread Id: " +  Thread.currentThread().getId());
            Assert.assertEquals(getDriver().getTitle(), "Google");
            System.out.println("Google1 Test Ended! " + "Thread Id: " +  Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        @Test
        public void GOOGLE2() {
            System.out.println("Google2 Test Started! " + "Thread Id: " +  Thread.currentThread().getId());
            getDriver().navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
            System.out.println("Google2 Test's Page title is: " + getDriver().getTitle() +" " + "Thread Id: " +  Thread.currentThread().getId());
            Assert.assertEquals(getDriver().getTitle(), "Google");
            System.out.println("Google2 Test Ended! " + "Thread Id: " +  Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        @Test
        public void GOOGLE3() {
            System.out.println("Google3 Test Started! " + "Thread Id: " +  Thread.currentThread().getId());
            getDriver().navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
            System.out.println("Google3 Test's Page title is: " + getDriver().getTitle() +" " + "Thread Id: " +  Thread.currentThread().getId());
            Assert.assertEquals(getDriver().getTitle(), "Google");
            System.out.println("Google3 Test Ended! " + "Thread Id: " +  Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    }
```

This is what I get in console:

```
Chrome_tests started ***
Firefox_tests started ***
Safari_tests started ***
*** Tests GOOGLE1 skipped...

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not create a session: The Safari instance is already paired with another WebDriver session.
Build info: version: '3.9.0', revision: '698b3178f0', time: '2018-02-05T14:56:13.134Z'
System info: host: 'Sashas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.88.183', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: 
Command duration or timeout: 25.97 seconds

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not create a session: The Safari instance is already paired with another WebDriver session.
Build info: version: '3.9.0', revision: '698b3178f0', time: '2018-02-05T14:56:13.134Z'
System info: host: 'Sashas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.88.183', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Sashas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.88.183', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@1b7d4b97
Build info: version: '3.9.0', revision: '698b3178f0', time: '2018-02-05T14:56:13.134Z'
System info: host: 'Sashas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.88.183', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@1b7d4b97
Build info: version: '3.9.0', revision: '698b3178f0', time: '2018-02-05T14:56:13.134Z'
System info: host: 'Sashas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.88.183', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Sashas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.88.183', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@3f5cca9c
Build info: version: '3.9.0', revision: '698b3178f0', time: '2018-02-05T14:56:13.134Z'
System info: host: 'Sashas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.88.183', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@3f5cca9c
Build info: version: '3.9.0', revision: '698b3178f0', time: '2018-02-05T14:56:13.134Z'
System info: host: 'Sashas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.88.183', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Sashas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.88.183', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown


Sep 11, 2019 7:07:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Sep 11, 2019 7:07:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
*** Running test method GOOGLE1...
Directory already exists: /Users/Sasha/Documents/Selenium_projects/testng_maven/SeleniumGrid/TestReport
*** Running test method GOOGLE2...
Google2 Test Started! Thread Id: 20
Google1 Test Started! Thread Id: 16
Google2 Test's Page title is: Google Thread Id: 20
Google1 Test's Page title is: Google Thread Id: 16
Google1 Test Ended! Thread Id: 16
*** Executed GOOGLE1 test method successfully...
Google2 Test Ended! Thread Id: 20
*** Executed GOOGLE2 test method successfully...
Sep 11, 2019 7:07:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
*** Running test method GOOGLE3...
Google3 Test Started! Thread Id: 20
Google3 Test's Page title is: Google Thread Id: 20
Google3 Test Ended! Thread Id: 20
*** Executed GOOGLE3 test method successfully...
Chrome_tests ending ***
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (freemarker.cache).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Test ignored.
*** Running test method GOOGLE1...

Test ignored.
*** Running test method GOOGLE2...
*** Tests GOOGLE2 skipped...
Firefox_tests ending ***

Test ignored.
*** Running test method GOOGLE1...
*** Tests GOOGLE1 skipped...

Test ignored.
*** Running test method GOOGLE2...
*** Tests GOOGLE2 skipped...
Safari_tests ending ***
===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 7, Passes: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 4
Configuration Failures: 3, Skips: 5
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

! https://prnt.sc/p4tzjr

Answer (score 1):

Safari will only handle 1 browser at a time, similar to IE and Edge.  Firefox and Chrome should be able to handle more. See [this link from apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/about_webdriver_for_safari)

> Only one Safari browser instance can be active at any given time, and
>   only one WebDriver session at a time can be attached to the browser
>   instance. These constraints ensure that the simulated behavior (mouse,
>   keyboard, touch, and so forth) accurately reflects what a user can do
>   in a macOS windowing environment and prevents tests from competing
>   with each other for window and keyboard focus.

Comment: Hey @Shannon M. Thanks for your comment! I know Safari can't handle more than one browser at a time, so in .xml file I've put parallel="methods" thread-count="1" for Safari. I wonder why tests fails when I'm trying to run test methods on Chrome and FF in parallel with the thread-count = 2 or more. I was under impression thread-safety approach would let me do that. Moreover, it works as expected with TestNG parallel execution, but not with Selenium Grid. Or is it not possible to do that with Grid.